# It is not displaying Select dropdown, the dropdown is box is empty, until pressed and one is picked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently using Vue.js, see code below.
When I remove from inside the select the `v-model="newItem.category"` section it starts to work, but I'm not sure why that is causing the issue?
Does anyone know how this works? Many thanks!

```
                            <div class="column">
                                <label class="label">Category</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <div class="select is-rounded">
                                        <select v-model="newItem.category">
                                            <option>Select Dropdown</option>
                                            <option>starter</option>
                                            <option>main</option>
                                            <option>side</option>
                                            <option>dessert</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely you didn't have `newItem.category` object in your code. And also, you need to put `value=""` to your options.

run this code to check

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data () {
  return {
    newItem : {
      category: 'main'
    }
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="column">
    <label class="label">Category</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select is-rounded">
        <select v-model="newItem.category">
          <option value="">Select Dropdown</option>
          <option value="starter">starter</option>
          <option value="main">main</option>
          <option value="side">side</option>
          <option value="dessert">dessert</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```